# Right way to print logged in user custom fields

Tags: 8, entities

What is the right way to get the field value for the account used from the currently logged-in user and print it in a template file, for example a block or a page template file?

I was trying to use the following code, but it doesn't work.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$user_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($user_id);
$variables['field_custom'] = $user_entity->field_custom->value;
```

In the template file, I am using this code.

```
{{ field_custom }}
```

Since the field custom is available, how can I print other field properties when the field is an entity reference field to a taxonomy term?

Comment: Nope, because this example becames value from node. I want the user fields value globally to use in Blocks and Page Twigs.

Comment: It doesn't matter if this comes from a node or a user. _Every_ entity reference field works this way

Comment: Im so sorry but its does not make any sense to me, I wanna print values from current user profile, not from node. Its should have a simple query. Even that, I have tryed use the example from indicate link, but no success. I have changed the {{ node.field.entity }} to {{ user.field.entity }} but no works. Also I have printed {{ user.displayname }} with success, now I need to print custom user fields.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the linked question says "node" - check the docs. Accessing entity fields and their values is all the same.

Comment: I appreciate all answers but you are indicating a link relationated with node entity reference, I let very clear I need print current logged-in user values on page or block templates, its have no relation with node. So I had to create a view for that as indicated in this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291275/how-can-i-print-user-field-values-in-page-html-twig. Also, for system menus is possible to use the https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token module using "current user" token.